# Java Play Framework finder with if else query

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I wrote the following piece of code to do selective queries, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
public static List<Item> selectBy(String name, String attr) {
    Query<Item> find = myFinderInstance;
    if (name != null) {
        find.where().eq("name", name);
    }
    if (attr != null) {
        find.where().eq("attr", attr);
    }

    return find.findList();
}
```

Basically I want the query to be able to work together. Either only by name, only by attribute or both. But with only 1 function.

Is this not possible or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add params conditionally to the `ExpressionList`, in this case if all params will be null it will return ALL objects:

```java
import com.avaje.ebean.ExpressionList;
import static com.avaje.ebean.Expr.eq;

// ...

public static List<Item> findByNameAndAttr(String name, String attr) {

    ExpressionList<Item> myQuery = find.where();

    if (name != null) myQuery.add(eq("name", name));
    if (attr != null) myQuery.add(eq("attr", attr));

    return myQuery.findList();
}
```

optionally if you prefer empty set if both params are `null` just start your method with condition:

```
if (name == null && attr == null) return new ArrayList<>();
```